# Trying to Send the message from to Amazon SQS

Tags: python, boto, amazon-sqs

I am using python and boto sqs for sending and receiving the message , Now I wanted to send the message to aws FIFO queue , but I don't find any resource of how to set the MessageGRoupID using the boto,there are plenty of resource available for sending message using boto3 , but I wanted to set the message group Id using the boto , can anyone help ,

my Current code is :

```
def _send_msg_to_Fifo_queue(queue_name,message_body,message_groupID,message_DeduplicationId):

    q = conn.get_queue(queue_name)

    if not q:
        # TODO idk, this should never happen, but log or something?
        pass
    m=Message()
    m.set_body(message_body)
    m.MessageGroupID=message_groupID
    q.write(m)
```

Comment: What is the problem with the current code? And why are you mentioning that you need to use boto, is there a reason you can not use boto3?

Comment: I cannot set the MessageGroupId using Boto , the above program set an error stating doesn't have attribute called MessageGroupId, I set the using message attribute although it says missing and as there are multiple places we need to install boto3 , as it is running on multiple servers. If there is any way I can set MEssageGroupIF using boto I don't want to install boto3

Comment: What about using [set_queue_attribute](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/sqs.html#boto.sqs.connection.SQSConnection.set_queue_attribute) it lets you set the attributes of the queue.

Comment: Tried, stack trace :boto.exception.SQSError: SQSError: 400 Bad Request
<?xml version="1.0"?><ErrorResponse xmlns="http://queue.amazonaws.com/doc/2012-11-05/"><Error><Type>Sender</Type><Code>InvalidAttributeName</Code><Message>Unknown Attribute MessageGroupId.</Message><Detail/></Error></ErrorResponse>

Comment: Well, I am gussing you are probably out of luck. If you check out the announcement from amazon about the FIFO queue [here](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/11/amazon-sqs-introduces-fifo-queues-with-exactly-once-processing-and-lower-prices-for-standard-queues/) it seems like it has gotten introduced only in 2016 and I guess at that time boto3 was already here so I am not even sure now that this has been backported to boto(2) at all!

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but I leave an answer for people who came to find a solution.

SQS send message request syntax:

```
response = queue.send_message(
    MessageBody='string',
    DelaySeconds=123,
    MessageAttributes={
        'string': {
            'StringValue': 'string',
            'BinaryValue': b'bytes',
            'StringListValues': [
                'string',
            ],
            'BinaryListValues': [
                b'bytes',
            ],
            'DataType': 'string'
        }
    },
    MessageSystemAttributes={
        'string': {
            'StringValue': 'string',
            'BinaryValue': b'bytes',
            'StringListValues': [
                'string',
            ],
            'BinaryListValues': [
                b'bytes',
            ],
            'DataType': 'string'
        }
    },
    MessageDeduplicationId='string',
    MessageGroupId='string'
)
```

So you can modify your code like this:

```
def _send_msg_to_Fifo_queue(queue_name,message_body,message_groupID,message_DeduplicationId):
    q = boto3.client('sqs').get_queue(queue_name)

    if not q:
        # TODO idk, this should never happen, but log or something?
        pass

    response = q.send_message(
        MessageBody=message_body,
        MessageGroupId=message_groupID,
        MessageDeduplicationId=message_DeduplicationId
    )
```

Official boto3 documentation: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sqs.html#SQS.Client.send_message